# Get posts of ONE taxonomy term of custom post type

Tags: posts, customization, taxonomy, terms

I have a custom post type called `portfolio` and a taxonomy called `locations`. In the taxonomy I have various terms, like `paris, berlin, london` etc.

How can I get only the posts which are related to one term, e.g. `paris`?

I am trying the following code, yet it gives me the ALL the posts of the taxonomy `portfolio` and not just of one term:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'locations' => 'paris'
);
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
<?php
    endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Are you sure `locations` is slug for that taxonomy? Could you show taxonomy registration code?

Comment: That `'taxonomy' => 'term_slug'` pattern is deprecated but should still work. Something else is wrong. Post [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) please.

Comment: Also the code tries to query a portfolio _post_type_ `'post_type' => 'portfolio'` but the question refers to "the posts of the _taxonomy_ 'portfolio'".

Answer (score 1):

You can try making the $args array more specific with:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'locations',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'paris'
        )
    )
);
```

Grabbed this snippet similar to one on the [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) page in the codex. Also, this is assuming that your custom post type is called "portfolio" and you have a custom taxonomy, "locations" and the term "paris". I say this because your question above says:

> I am trying the following code, yet it gives me the ALL the posts of
>   the taxonomy 'portfolio' and not just of one term:

So "portfolio" is your custom post type, correct? Anyway, let us know if you find the problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add a slug to your taxonomy :

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'taxonomy_slung' )
```